# Выбрать layout для формы в Java

Tags: java, layout, swing

Не могу выбрать `Layout` для `JFrame`. Задача состоит в том чтобы элементы(панели) в форме расположить как здесь

[image]

Панели будет разные в высоту но выровнены по ширине. Пробовал `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout` и `FlowLayout` пока выходила сплошная пляска компонентов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

думаю, тут как раз GridBagLayout и подойдёт... надо только разобраться с ним,
вот [ссылка](http://frolov-lib.ru/programming/javasamples/vol5/vol5_5/index.html), тут описание есть и пример.

Comment: спасибо пробую.

Comment: GridBagLayout то что нужно, спасибо.

Comment: ну вот и отлично, что разобрались!)

Answer (score 0):

судя по картинке вам нужен grid layout, только для того, чтоб создать 2 колонки (2 панели), а дальше можно уже "пихать как попало". к сожалению если использовать FlowLayout и не задавать ширину компоненты могут сползать в одну строчку, поэтому лучше сразу использовать специализированный layout manager. код создает окошко, 2 колонки по 3 панели в каждой. у каждой панели разная высота:

```
/// add random height text area
private static void updateLabel(JPanel panel) {

    Random r = new Random();
    int random = r.nextInt(15) + 1;

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea(random, 15);

    panel.add(textArea);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create and customize frame
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    f.setSize(400, 400);

    // create panels
    JPanel left = new JPanel();
    left.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    JPanel right = new JPanel();
    right.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    // add main panels to the frame
    f.add(left);
    f.add(right);

    // set layout managers
    left.setLayout(new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    right.setLayout(new BoxLayout(right, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    // add components
    JPanel black = new JPanel();
    black.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    JPanel red = new JPanel();
    red.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JPanel green = new JPanel();
    green.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    JPanel cyan = new JPanel();
    cyan.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    JPanel gray = new JPanel();
    gray.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    JPanel orange = new JPanel();
    orange.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

    left.add(black);
    left.add(red);
    left.add(green);

    right.add(cyan);
    right.add(gray);
    right.add(orange);

    updateLabel(black);
    updateLabel(red);
    updateLabel(green);
    updateLabel(cyan);
    updateLabel(gray);
    updateLabel(orange);

    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TableLayout` c 1-й строчкой и двумя колонками (фактически 2 горизонтальные ячейки)
Далее, внутри каждой из ячеек делаем `FlowLayout`

Answer (score 0):

тебе нужен `BoxLayout`

сначала делаешь панель и вставляешь туда `BoxLayout`

```
JPanel pnelBig=new JPanel();
panelBig.addLayout(new BoxLayout(panelBig, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

потом вставляешь туда две панели с `BoxLayout` и `Y_AXIS`, а в них уже твои панели